# Is there a way to connect a IBM quantum lab code to an Unreal Engine project?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I would like to know whether someone tried this before, I'm interested in be able to connect this tools. I know that Unreal Engine has a plugin to program with python, that all I know. I'll really appreciate your comments.

Comment: The IBM qiskit language (which is IBM's quantum language) is just a package in python, so I'm guessing that you can use the plugin to program with python and code in python with the qiskit package. (I know nothing about the unreal engine so I'm just going from what you've said). To learn more about qiskit check out: https://qiskit.org/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.